# why one of my github branch GUI looks different from the other branches?

Tags: github, git-branch

[image: The first image]

[image: The second image]

I noticed this (maybe)issue just an hour ago.

In the first image, GUI is normal github branch I used to know.

But branch in the second image, something is different from normal-looking branches.

There are a total of five branches in that project, but only that one branch(in the second image) has a different look.

I can't figure out what different is exist and even don't know this could be an issue.

If there anybody knows about this. Please give me an advice.

I googled "github branch GUI looks different from" or something, but can't find anything.

Comment: Hi There, Afaik. GitHub is slowly rolling out and testing its new UI. This is not an issue.

Comment: Yes, see: https://github.blog/changelog/2022-11-09-introducing-an-all-new-code-search-and-code-browsing-experience/#the-all-new-code-browsing-experience